# Django: ¿Cómo identificar usuario autenticado en template de editar usuarios?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, navbar

Estoy programando en Django una aplicación web en el que el usuario se debe iniciar sesión y en todo template debe aparecer en el navbar su correo electrónico (`{{user.email}}`), lo cual lo conseguí. Cuento con un template donde se gestiona los usuarios existentes en el sistema, el problema está en el template para editar usuarios, cuando se selecciona editar un determinado usuario el navbar cambia del correo electrónico del usuario logueado al correo del usuario que estoy editando, cuando salgo de la vista para editar usuario, el problema solo está presente en ese template en específico.

Mi `urls.py` en la app es el siguiente:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from .views import usuarios_View,create_user_view, update_user_view, delete_user_view
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from . import views


app_name = "usuarios"
urlpatterns = [
    path('usuarios/',login_required(usuarios_View.as_view(),login_url="/"),name="usurios_view"),
    path('nuevo-usuario/',login_required(create_user_view.as_view(),login_url="/"),name="create_new_user"),
    path('update-usuario/<int:pk>/',login_required(update_user_view.as_view(),login_url="/"),name="update_user"),
    path('delete-usuario/<int:pk>/',login_required(delete_user_view.as_view(),login_url="/"),name="delete_user")
]
```

En `view.py` para editar el usuario tengo el siguiente view class:

```
class update_user_view(UpdateView):
    template_name='usuarios/form-user.html'
    form_class = UsuariosForm
    model = User
    success_url=reverse_lazy('usuarios:usurios_view')
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['gestion'] = 'edit'
        return context
```

En el template de editar usuario:

```
<form method="POST">
                    <!-- Security token -->
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <!-- Using the formset -->
                    {% if gestion == 'new' %}
                        <h1>Nuevo Usuario</h1>
                    {% else %}
                        <h1>Editar Usuario</h1>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="row" style="text-align:left;">
                        <div class="col">
                            {{ form.as_p }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <a name="" id="" class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'usuarios:usurios_view' %}" 
                            role="button"  style="width:100%">
                                <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Volver</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" style="width:100%">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-floppy-disk"></i> Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>              
                </form>
```

La siguiente línea corresponde a mostrar el correo del usuario logueado en el navbar ubicado en `base.py`

```
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">{{user.email}}<i class="fas fa-user fa-fw"></i></a>
```

Hasta el momento no logro solucionarlo, ¿Cómo podría lograrlo?

Comment: Perdona no entendí el problema, puedes explicarlo mejor?

Comment: @Christian si. Si el usuario con email admin@admin.com inicia sesión, se muestra este mail en el navbar en todas las vistas de la aplicación. Entre las vistas de la aplicación está la de editar un usuario (ya que soy admin puedo editar datos de todos los demás usuarios), si intento editar el usuario con correo user1@test.com, en el template de edtar usuario en el navbar se cambia el correo de admin@admin.com a user1@test.com. ¿Me explico bien?

Comment: Sip, lo entiendo. Y cual es el problema? Que no se cambia?

Comment: El problema está en que no debería cambiarse el correo del navbar al correo del usuario que estoy editando, debería mostrar el correo del usuario logueado en el navbar en todas las vistas incluida la de editar usuario.